# Why is fulltext index search slower than like in mysql?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using mysql.

I use a fulltext index for searching, I know this is faster than a like search.

But in my actual query, fulltext index search is much slower than like.

```
#1
SELECT ...
FROM CAT
INNER JOIN DOCTOR ON CAT.DOCTORID = DOCTOR.ID
WHERE ( CAT.NAME1 LIKE '%{searchKeyword}%'
  OR CAT.NAME2 LIKE '%{searchKeyword}%'
  OR CAT.NAME3 LIKE '%{searchKeyword}%'
  OR DOCTOR.NAME LIKE '%{searchKeyword}%'
)

#2 
SELECT ...
FROM CAT
INNER JOIN DOCTOR ON CAT.DOCTORID = DOCTOR.ID
WHERE MATCH(CAT.NAME1) AGAINST('+"{searchKeyword}"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  OR MATCH(CAT.NAME2) AGAINST('+"{searchKeyword}"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  OR MATCH(CAT.NAME3) AGAINST('+"{searchKeyword}"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  OR MATCH(DOCTOR.NAME) AGAINST('+"{searchKeyword}"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
```

If I change '+"{searchKeyword}"' to '{searchKeyword}' in #2, it takes the same  time.

I know fulltext index is faster than like, am I wrong?

The index was created separately for cat.name1,2,3 using `ngram` parser. And n=2

Time required when using like : 0.067s
Time required when using match-against : 2.67s

The data is about 400,000 cases.

Comment: If you defined a single fulltext index for three columns, then you're using `MATCH()` wrong. You need to name the same three columns in one call to `MATCH()`, not three separate calls. I don't think it can use the index if you don't name the same columns, in the same order. Verify that with `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. sorry but the sql has changed can you check again?

Comment: For query #2 - you have 4 separate FT indices, and in most cases their usage will be slower that 4 LIKE operators with full table scan. For FTS to be faster the amount of selected rows should be tiny (approximately - less than at least 1%). PS. For #2 - 4 separate queries and UNION DISTINCT may be more fast. PPS. *I know fulltext index is faster than like, am I wrong?* Depends on the query and data. In your case the OR usage makes your statement doubtful.

Comment: I try to have a result that matches even one name. It's fast because it's separated according to your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` kills performance.  Almost always it disables any use of `INDEXes` of any kind.

What to do...

Have an extra column that (redundantly) contains all the search words in it.  Apply a `FULLTEXT` index on it.  No `ORs`.

With that, `FULLTEXT` will be faster and will scale much better than `LIKE` with a leading wildcard.

(Akina's `UNION DISTINCT` is slower than a combined `FULLTEXT`; it is useful for messier situations than what you have.)

**Revised**

Your query is confusing... You want to find all

1. All cats with a given name, if any, plus the doctor(s) that treated those cats, and/or
2. All doctors with a given name, if any, plus all the cats they treated?

First, do those as two separate queries.  Better yet, force the user to provide *either* a cat name *or* a doctor name.  Those are too dissimilar to try to mix them.

Then the CAT query is something like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM CAT
    WHERE MATCH(name1, name2, name3)
          AGAINST('+"{searchKeyword}"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Together with

```
FULLTEXT(name1, name2, name3)
```

That Select could be JOINed to DOCTOR, if desired.

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd paragraph TT. Can you explain a little more easily?

Comment: @KunAguero - OK, I revised my answer.

Comment: thank you. If I use join in the way you wrote, the output is different than what I want. I want to match if only one of the four names.

Comment: What if I call my CAT "Rin Tin Tin"?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment check. Against '+"Rin" +"Tin" +"Tin"' for all names.

Comment: Seems like youi need `MATCH(...) AGAINST ('+Rin +Tin +Tin' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.  But that means app code to insert the `+`.  I doubt if the duplication of `Tin` matters.